# Update parent with text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, textinput

Okay, so I have a dialog with inputs. When closing the dialog, there is a function to update the parent UL. The parent LI within that UL should have the text input value. It's not working. Please help. I put an alert in my update, to see if the value makes it there. No luck. http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/

**jQuery**

```
    $("input.save").click(function () {         
      $('#numbers tbody tr').each(function(i,v){            
        var ele = $(v);
        var adjName = $('input[name=adjName]',ele).val();
        parent.updateParent2(adjName);
      });
    });   
//////////////////////////////
function updateParent2(adjName){
    alert(adjName);
      var ul = $('ul.adjTabs');
      var li = ul.find('li:first').clone().val(adjName);
      li.find('li:first input');
      li.appendTo(ul)//.val(adjName);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
    <table id="numbers">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="cloneableRow" class="prototype">        
          <td >
          <input type="text" name="adjName" value="" class="text214 apni"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<input type='button' value='save' class='save' />

            <ul class="tabs adjTabs">
              <li class="selected"><a href="#">Adjustments ABC</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Adjustments DEF</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I'm confused .. do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/1/

Comment: parent means iframes/frames. Are you using them?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Almost. The li does correctly clone there, but rather than "Adjustments ABC" I need it to match the text input.

Comment: So you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/7/

Comment: @ExplosionPills So, let's say I want the text of an input and 2 dropdowns in that li. Example input - select select with the dash "-". How can I go about doing that? jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/8

Comment: @triplethreat77 seems more complicated because you're iterating over table rows, but each input has a row.  Why are you iterating over them?

Comment: The dialog that I have for this project has multiple variables with text input and drop downs that make one li title. I know it's complicated, but this is how it should work with user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/6/

You can see the changes here:

```
$("input.save").click(function () {         
  $('#numbers tbody tr').each(function(i,v){            
    var ele = $(v);
    var adjName = $('input[name=adjName]',ele).val();
    updateParent2(adjName);
  });
});   

//////////////////////////////
function updateParent2(adjName){
  var ul = $('ul.adjTabs');
  var li = ul.find('li:first').clone();
  li.children('a').text(adjName);
  li.find('li:first input');
  li.appendTo(ul)//.val(adjName);
}
```

Comment: This will not work with HTML. I need a clone. Using html(), it is not longer a link and will carry no CSS attributes I give it.

Comment: You can't set `val` of `li`, you need to set `text` or `html`. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/6/ this sets value of the `a` which is child of the `li`.

Comment: Perfect, thant's what I needed. :D

Comment: So, let's say I want the text of an input and 2 dropdowns in that li. Example input - select select with the dash "-". How can I go about doing that? http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/8/

Comment: You can join this chat room to continue the discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25311/discussing-problem

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle was not refencing jQuery.  I fixed that and your bug: http://jsfiddle.net/C9EbG/3/

The bug was you should just call `updateParent2(adjName)` not `parent.updateParent2(adjName)`

Comment: The list is cloned, yes but I need the new list to be the value of the text input.